# Create Cookie Banner

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

The goal is to create a simple Cookie Banner using HTML, JavaScript, CSS+, and PHP.

We already created the HTML and the CSS but we can't figure out how to set the Cookies (Facebook Pixel + Google Analytics) only when the User clicks on ACCEPT.

Comment: I really liked the question and I too am interested in knowing the answer. I hope there is a way to do this.

Comment: you need to show what you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example setting a cookie with JavaScript for a cookie banner I used myself (didn't wanted to use a library).

HTML:

```
<div class="cookie-banner js-cookie-banner">
    We use ...
    <button class="js-cookie-dismiss">Accept</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript (uses ES6, so transpiling might be necessary, otherwise browser support should be fine):

```
// Key under which name the cookie is saved
const cookieName = 'cookieconsent';
// The value could be used to store different levels of consent
const cookieValue = 'dismissed';

function dismiss() {
    const date = new Date();
    // Cookie is valid 1 year: now + (days x hours x minutes x seconds x milliseconds)
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    // Set cookie
    document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${cookieValue};expires=${date.toUTCString()};path=/`;

    // You probably want to remove the banner
    document.querySelector('.js-cookie-banner').remove();
}

// Get button element
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-cookie-dismiss');
// Maybe cookie consent is not present
if (buttonElement) {
    // Listen on button click
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', dismiss);
}
```

The markup of the cookie consent banner should only be included by the PHP application if the cookie is not set. Therefore use something like this:

```
if (!(array_key_exists('cookieconsent', $_COOKIE) && $_COOKIE['cookieconsent'] === 'dismissed')) {
    // Output the HTML
}
```

You could also include the JavaScript only on this condition. Alternatively, you could check if the cookie is set in JavaScript:

```
function isDismissed() {
    // Get all cookies as string
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    // Separate cookies
    const cookies = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (let cookie of cookies) {
        cookie = cookie.trim();
        // Check if cookie is present
        if (cookie === `${cookieName}=${cookieValue}`) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Check it out on CodePen, Cookies are not supported by StackOverflow:  https://codepen.io/KiwiKilian/pen/PgaVMb

You can see if the cookie is set in the developer tools, e.g. in [Chrome dev tools under application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWmly.png) and also remove it again.